# Why is my linux screen blurry on my monitor but it isn't when running Windows?

Tags: centos, monitors

I have a linux machine running Centos connected to two ViewSonic monitors. One is 22 inches and the other is 24 inches. I also have a Windows machine connected only to the 24 inch monitor pressing the input switch to go back and forth between Linux and Windows.

The thing I noticed is that on the monitor that has both Linux and Windows connected to it, when running Linux, the screen seems somewhat blurry and the 'blacks' on the screen are not as deep as it is on the other ViewSonic monitor but on this same 24 inch monitor when switched to Windows machine, the same sharpness and color levels that are seen on the 22 inch are also now on the 24 inch.

Is it a graphics driver issue because the Linux screen on the 22 inch seems perfectly fine but it seems like there is some sort of "blurry" filter that is overlayed on the 24 inch. The best way I can describe it is that "ClearType" thing that is found on Windows when used on text.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a bootable flash drive test to see if the screen is blurry with the new os.

If the blurriness isn't there updating the drivers is about the only thing you can do.(unless there is a linux config option for quality of frames displayed vs frame rate)...

Also try booting a linux os on the windows machine to see what occurs. Is the screen blurry on post or only after the os is booted?

Comment: In my opinion it may be also an issue with choosing proper subpixel layout (small changes in "sharpness" of the text/graphics) or even a resolution (bigger changes). Different black may be a different color profile maybe?